# Export DataGridView into Excel 2013 with "text" cell formating for all cell

Tags: c#

I have this code for exporting data into excel:

```
private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
{
    string stOutput = "";
    // Export titles:
    string sHeaders = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
        sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
    stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
    // Export data.
    for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        string stLine = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
        stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
    }
    Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
    byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}  
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
    sfd.FileName = "export.xls";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
        ToCsV(dataGridView2, sfd.FileName); // Here dataGridview1 is your grid view name 
    }  
}
```

but when i open excel file, cell's have formating, i want have all cell with text formating.

Comment: Are you creating a CSV ??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply create an excel file like creating a .txt file. What you are doing now is creating a CSV file and opening it in excel. In such a case you do not preserve style information [Formatting as you require].

If you want to create a well formatted excel file [.XLSX file as in Open XMl file formats] you need to use a library. They contains XML file structures zipped together and you can define what each cell format should be.

There are many options, [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is a third party library . [Open XMl SDK 2.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is the Microsoft's recommendation. Also you have the other option of using Office [Interops](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm) which is also a solution you can use.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file with XLS extension is not an Excel file. MS Excel knows to read a CSV file and display it in a sheet, but is not a real XLS or XLSX file. Furthermore, a CSV file cannot store the cell formatting, only the data.

To export an Excel file you need an Excel library, like [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) for example.

Take a look at this code sample about [exporting DataGridView to Excel with cell formatting](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-datagridview-to-excel.html).

I do not recommend Office Interop and Microsoft either. For more details see [why not to use OLE Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) from Microsoft point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are saving the data as a plain CSV you can't have any "cell formatting". Generally speaking, what you see in Excel is always its "(too)smart interpretation" of the data found inside imported file (e.g. if you have something that appears like a "number", it automatically sets the cell format to show numbers up, thus with right alignment).

To force Excel to define the item as a text value, simply put it inside double quotes and precede it with an equal sign:

```
stLine += "=\"" + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\"\t";
```

This will write 132 as:
="132"
and Excel will show it up as string 132 (i.e. left aligned) instead of the number 132.